# Proof that $\sin(x)$ don't have limit to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I just used the Heine's definition.

Let $\alpha,\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sin(\alpha)=a$ and $\sin(\delta)=b$. Let $(u_{n})=\alpha+2\pi n$ and $(v_{n})=\delta+2\pi n$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

So one have,

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} u_{n}=+\infty$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} v_{n}=+\infty$$

But,

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(u_{n})=a$

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(v_{n})=b$

Because these last limits aren't equal, the sine function don't have limit to infinity. Is this proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: It is a correct proof as long as you take $a \neq b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another proof would be to note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\lfloor x \rfloor \pi) - \sin ( 2\lfloor x \rfloor \pi) \right)  = 1$, hence $\sin$ has no limit as $x \to \infty$. (If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$, then 
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( f(x+y)-f(x) \right) = 0$ for all $y$).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach: for any integer m $\in$ {1,5,9,13...} $\sin( m\pi/2) =1$ and this will occur infinitely many times as x $\rightarrow \infty$.  For any integer m sin(m$\pi$) = 0.  So you have a subsequence  of sinx which converges to 1 and another that converges to 0.

In order to have a limit it must be true that every subsequence converges to the same number.  So there is no limit.